# How to reload div without blink

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am new to web development I have HTML webpage that retrieves data from the database and shows information according to the data I want to retrieve data each second without making web page blink please apply it to the following code because I didn't understand how can I apply it using previous solutions.

```
        <style>
.containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; } 
body { background-color: #99BD91;}
.content {margin: auto;}
</style>
<div class="containerdiv" style="width:100%;" >
<img src="paaa.jpg" style="width:100%"; >

<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM `data1`");
$storeArray = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$storeArray[] =  $row['value'];  } // retrive data from database and store it in array
?>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) You really need to find a more up-to-date tutorial; the `mysql_` extension is practically dead (and will be come Dec 31). 2) AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by blink. If you mean without the page refreshing, the only way to do it would be with AJAX.
This link may help you if you want to try:
[W3Schools - PHP AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp)